# What is the best way to serialize circular referenced objects?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Better that should be text format. The best would be json, with some standart to pointers. Binary would be also good. Remember in old times, soap has standart for this. What you suggest?

Comment: Please, clarify the question and add more information: So, do you want text or binary format? Why do you say JSON would be best? Why are you serializing the graph? How much does size matter? Do you need to access the serialized data from another language? How does the graph look like? Can't you serialize it in a way that doesn't contain circular references and restore them during deserialization?

Comment: @TMB Yes, standard is correct. That's a common mistake in some languages, e.g. german.

Comment: YAML handles references just fine. You may want to use that.

Comment: @Mark ok, thanks, i didn't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No problem with [binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) whatsoever:

```
[Serializable]
public class CircularTest
{
    public CircularTest[] Children { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var circularTest = new CircularTest();
        circularTest.Children = new[] { circularTest };
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = File.Create("serialized.bin"))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, circularTest);
        }

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead("serialized.bin"))
        {
            circularTest = (CircularTest)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

A [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) can also cope with circular references, you just need to use a special constructor and indicate this and it will spit XML:

```
public class CircularTest
{
    public CircularTest[] Children { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var circularTest = new CircularTest();
        circularTest.Children = new[] { circularTest };
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(
            circularTest.GetType(), 
            null, 
            100, 
            false, 
            true, // <!-- that's the important bit and indicates circular references
            null
        );
        serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), circularTest);
    }
}
```

And the latest version of [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) supports circular references as well with JSON:

```
public class CircularTest
{
    public CircularTest[] Children { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var circularTest = new CircularTest();
        circularTest.Children = new[] { circularTest };
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
        { 
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects 
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(circularTest, Formatting.Indented, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Children": [
    {
      "$ref": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

which I guess is what you was asking about.